# Meaning of "at least Dick Turpin wore a mask"

Tags: meaning, idioms, meaning-in-context, british-english

I tried to sell my stuff and one of the guys asked me if I could bargain on the item and I said no. He replied with the message,

> At least Dick Turpin wore a mask.

What does that mean?

Comment: Dick Turpin was a famous, British highwayman in the past. See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Turpin

Comment: I do have to wonder, though, why you didn't just ask him right then and there.

Comment: I did but he didn't reply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dick Turpin was a famous thief. What they mean by *at least Dick Turpin wore a mask* is that at least Dick Turpin attempted to conceal his identity when committing robbery/burglary.

The implication is that someone is trying to rob (or burgle) someone else flagrantly.

Answer (score 4):

He's implying that like famous highwayman [Dick Turpin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Turpin) (wikipedia) you are trying to rob him (rip him off, if you like).

He hopefully doesn't mean it too seriously though, but doesn't want to bargain.

Comment: Having worked in pubs in the UK for 20 years, I can assure you that every time the prices went up, at least one customer (thinking that they are witty) would say "at least Dick Turpin wore a mask", implying that the customers are being ripped off.  Hence, I've upvoted this answer.

Comment: I'd never heard it in that context before - good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While it is obvious Turpin wore a mask to avoid being recognised, the buyer is suggesting a seller has a 'bare faced' cheek to ask a hefty price and is guilty of such blatant 'highway robbery' that Dick himself would be embarrassed to attempt it in person. 
It doesn't really work well in the written form.